# Problemas com recursão em c

Tags: c, recursão

Estou tentando aprender recursão e estou com duvida em uma questão que estava fazendo em c, preciso somar quantos números de um vetor com n elementos são maiores que um numero x. Essa recursão simplesmente não entra na cabeça, preciso de uma clareada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int busca(int v[], int n, int k)
{
  int x = 0;
  if(n == 1)
  {
    if( k < v[0])
     x= x + 1;



    }


  else
  {  
    if(k <  v[n])
      x = x+ 1;
      busca( v, n-1 ,k);
    }



      return x;


}


int main()
{
  int n, k,x;



  printf("DIGITE A QUANTIDADE DE ELEMENTOS DO VETOR:");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  int v[n];
  int i;

  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    printf("Digite o elemento %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
  }

  printf("Digite um numero: ");
  scanf("%d", &k);


//printf ("%d",
printf("x = %d", busca(v, n, k));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursão que pretende fazer resume-se à seguinte lógica:

- Verificar se o item em que vai é maior que o `k` e contabilizar 1 caso seja ou 0 caso contrário
- Chamar a mesma função recursivamente para o próximo elemento somando o seu resultado

Implementação:

```
int busca(int v[], int n, int k) {
    if (--n<0) return 0; //se chegou ao fim retorna 0

    return (v[n]>k?1:0) + busca(v, n, k);//contabilizar 0 ou 1 e somar com a próxima busca
}
```

O `main` está a fazer acessos ao array fora das posições válidas:

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

Está a ir de `1` a `n`, mas os arrays começam em `0`. Logo tem de começar em `0` e ir até `n-1`.

Depois desse ajuste ficamos com o `main` assim:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    printf("DIGITE A QUANTIDADE DE ELEMENTOS DO VETOR:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int v[n], i, k;    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Digite o elemento %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }

    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("x = %d", busca(v, n, k));

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/BYKX7H)